# How to split file into smaller by first number in second column

Tags: python, text, io

So my data looks like:

```
1 3456542  5 may 2014
2 1245678  4 may 2014
3 4256876  2 may 2014
4 5643156  6 may 2014
.....
```

The goal is to sort it by the 2nd column then separate the rows based on the first number in the 2nd column (i.e. 3456542 goes to subs_3.txt, 1245678 goes to subs_1.txt...).  The output is totally wrong and gives me 6 files with what appears to be random rows in them.  Any suggestions?

```
import csv
from operator import itemgetter

file_lines = []
with open("subs.txt", "r") as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=" ")
    for row in reader:
        file_lines.append(row)

file_lines.sort(key=itemgetter(1))

with open("sorted_subs.txt", "w") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=" ")
    for row in file_lines:
        writer.writerow(row)

for row in file_lines:
    file_num = row[1[1]
    with open("file_{0}.txt".format(file_num), "w") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=" ")
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the lines that go to same file together and then just loop over the groups in order to write the files:

```
from itertools import groupby

for k, g in groupby(file_lines, key=lambda x: x[1][0]):
    with open("file_{0}.txt".format(k), "w") as f:
        csv.writer(f, delimiter=" ").writerows(g)
```

**Update:** `groupby` will group the lines based on the first number in second column. It will return the key used for grouping and iterator containing the grouped items. Since `file_lines` is already sorted we know that all items belonging to same group will be returned within one group. Here's a short example how it works, note that test data is different than in original question in order to demonstrate grouping:

```
from itertools import groupby

lst = [
    ['2', '1245678', '', '4', 'may', '2014'], 
    ['1', '3456542', '', '5', 'may', '2014'], 
    ['3', '3256876', '', '2', 'may', '2014'], 
    ['4', '5643156', '', '6', 'may', '2014']
]

for k, g in groupby(lst, key=lambda x: x[1][0]):
    print('key: {0}, items: {1}'.format(k, list(g)))
```

Output:

```
key: 1, items: [['2', '1245678', '', '4', 'may', '2014']]
key: 3, items: [['1', '3456542', '', '5', 'may', '2014'], ['3', '3256876', '', '2', 'may', '2014']]
key: 5, items: [['4', '5643156', '', '6', 'may', '2014']]
```

Comment: I get this error message.  tried googling it but don't understand it in this context: 

    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-42-35450c36d948> in <module>()
    21 for k, g in groupby(file_lines, key=lambda x: x[1][0]):
    22     with open("file_{0}.txt".format(k), "wb") as f:
    ---> 23         csv.writer(f, delimiter=" ").writerows(g)

    TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str

Comment: @e1v1s That was caused by `b` in the file mode on Python 3, I changed the mode back to `w` so now it should work ok.

Comment: Thanks, can you break down the code in english for me, especially the first line, I'm pretty new and don't fully get it.

Comment: @e1v1s: Added short explanation, you could also refer Python docs.

Comment: @ niemmi: So if I wanted to separate by date I could leave everything the same except:

    for k, g in groupby(file_lines, key=lambda x: x[3]):

Comment: @e1v1s Well you could but note that it only groups consecutive items in the iterable together. So if you have `'AABBAA`' you'd get three different groups where keys would be `A B A`. In your original question you had already sorted rows with the number which first digit was used group the items so this wasn't an issue.